# Xampp port 80 already use

Tags: apache, xampp

I have installed XAMPP on my pc and I change all port from '443' to '4433' and '80' to '8080' but when I start Apache it say me that port '80' is already use but Apache must use '8080' and when I go to 'http://localhost/' it display me a 404 error then I don't know what to do.

With `netstat -ao` on 'cmd' I see that port '80' is using by a program whit 'PID=4' and I see in the task manager that this PID is for "NT Kernel & System" so I can not kill it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the port number http://localhost:8080
it seems like you have changed the port from here C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf

## Listen 12.34.56.78:80 to 8080

Listen 80 to 8080
Alternative if want to use port 80 then
If the skype is open try to change the port from the select options(80/443).Sometimes this is the problem.IIS server if running it might use the same port
You can use some tools to kill the process for example, currports, TCPview etc.Hope it helps to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Windows 10. I had to stop the IIS service: "World Wide Web Publishing Service". After stopping/disabling it, it freed up port 80.
Press Ctrl+Shift+Esc (opens taskmanager), Services and stop W3SVC service - World Wide Web Publishing Service;

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.

1. You change your port 80 to 8080.
2. Therefore to log localhost, you have to use http://localhost:8080/xampp/ and not http://localhost/xampp/

Then when you use xampp control panel, sometime you have to face same problem as I was.

1. Can't go to admin page using admin button in mysql. To get rid of this problem you can do following changes.

Go to xampp control panel.
Using config button open configuration of control pannel. Then click service and port setting and under appache setting you can change your main port 80 to 8080.