# problem with xampp installation: Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free

Tags: xampp

after installation of xampp, I got this Problem:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60SiH.png)

i am using windows

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728663/xampp-port-80-already-use an answer to your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XAMPP Port 80 Error In Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655998/xampp-port-80-error-in-windows-7)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xampp port 80 already use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728663/xampp-port-80-already-use)